# Javascript convert numbers to hyperlinks within text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to parse a string that contains numbers, to make each number clickable with a hyperlink that contains that number, for a number of cells in a table.

I have a string that could be formated something like: `12345, 54321, 13542` or `12345 and 54321 and 13542` or even `Number12345` etc. There is no limit to the amount of numbers within the cell.

I would like for these numbers to be hyperlinks something like:

```
http://www.example.com/example?q=12345
http://www.example.com/example?q=54321
http://www.example.com/example?q=13542
```

I'd be grateful to hear about any way in JS/JQuery to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use regex functions.  It's a one-line function call - search google for "javascript regex replace".

Comment: If "Number12345" is a valid number, I would like to see some definition of what a "number" could be, not just examples. Could "Anything12345Whatsoever" be a number, or is it vital that the string part says "Number"?

Comment: Your best way to proceed would be `/(\d+)/g`

Comment: Number, as @hjpotter92 says, would be satisfied by `/(\d+)g`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your table cells only have text in them, this should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myTable td").each(function(){
        var text = $(this).html();
        text = text.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<a href="http://example.com/$1">$1</a>');
        $(this).html(text);
    });
});
```

I set up an example on JsFiddle to test it out: http://jsfiddle.net/EzfzU/.

Comment: I used same approach a while ago

Comment: Your use of `*` (0 or more occurrences) yields a lot more matches than `+` (1 or more occurrences). If you [look at the markup you're producing](http://jsfiddle.net/L6N35/), it's a bit messier than the `+` would've been. Also, your pattern does not accept zeroes, but I suppose that's a simple typo, (albeit one you would've avoided if you would've used `\d` rather than `[1-9]`).

Comment: I used this answer but I did substitute the regex `/([1-9]*)/` for `/(\d+)/`

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following function, which is a modification of a previous answer

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myTable td").each(function(){
        var text = $(this).html();
        text = text.replace(/(\d+)/gm, '<a href="http://example.com/$1">$1</a>');
        $(this).html(text);
    });
});
```

Note the following differences:

- \d+ to capture any numbers with a greedy match (ensuring at least 1 number exists)
- the /gm modifier to ensure that even strings with line breaks have their contents matched

Comment: I'm not certain why this was downvoted, as the answer accepted will not work if there are any zeroes in cell.